# astropy exits none zero on header update

Tags: python, astropy, fits

I have an astronomical image `fits` format with WCS (World Coordinate System) in its header.

I want to do some morphological operations on the image and understandably I want to correct the WCS.

Say I crop the image. Applying to the header would be:

```
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS

header: Header = fits.getheader("sample.fits")

x, y, w, h = 100, 100, 200, 100

wcs = WCS(header)
new_wcs = wcs[y:y + h, x:x + w]
```

I can confirm new_wcs is correct by checking the new pixel to sky coordinates:

```
print(wcs.pixel_to_world(2, 2))
print(new_wcs.pixel_to_world(2, 2))
```

The only problem here would be that I lost the information in the original header. So I tried to update the old header.

```
added_header: Header = header.copy()
added_header.extend(new_wcs.to_header(), unique=True, update=True)
added_header_wcs = WCS(added_header)
```

The whole code would be:

```
from astropy.io.fits import Header

from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS

header: Header = fits.getheader("sample.fits")

x, y, w, h = 100, 100, 200, 100

wcs = WCS(header)
new_wcs = wcs[y:y + h, x:x + w]
added_header: Header = header.copy()
added_header.extend(new_wcs.to_header(), unique=True, update=True)
added_header_wcs = WCS(added_header) # boom

print(wcs.pixel_to_world(2, 2))
print(new_wcs.pixel_to_world(2, 2))
print(added_header_wcs.pixel_to_world(2, 2))
```

However at the `added_header_wcs = WCS(added_header)` line python crashes:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

I tried to enable logging for astropy, but I was not able to do so.

Before creating an issue I wanted to ask more knowledgeable people. Where do I do wrong?

PS: copying a new header is not the problem, as I tried to modify the original header.

PS: the sample data: http://www.astropy.org/astropy-data/tutorials/FITS-images/HorseHead.fits

### Edit:

Executing the same code with a none-conda interpreter threw an exception:

```
WARNING: FITSFixedWarning: 'celfix' made the change 'Invalid parameter value'. [astropy.wcs.wcs]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[PATH]\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(WCS(new_header).pixel_to_world(2, 2))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[PATH]\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\astropy\wcs\wcs.py", line 600, in __init__
    self.wcs.set()
ValueError: ERROR 5 in wcsset() at line 2808 of file cextern\wcslib\C\wcs.c:
Invalid parameter value.
ERROR 4 in linset() at line 737 of file cextern\wcslib\C\lin.c:
Failed to initialize distortion functions.
ERROR 3 in tpdset() at line 1945 of file cextern\wcslib\C\dis.c:
Unrecognized field name for TPD on axis 1: DQ1.DSS.AMD.1.
```

Comment: 0xC0000005 is the Windows error code for an access violation (AKA "segfault"). This would be a bug in C code underlying the WCS module, probably because it was passed a header that was malformed in some way that was never expected (an error that isn't checked for). You should try to print the header and see if it actually makes sense. It's been too long since I worked on WCS with FITS to give you a better answer off the top of my head, but I don't think you need to go through so many hoops to update the WCS data in an existing header. I think there's a better way.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I was hoping you find this. :). I hope I can find the better way. :)

Comment: It looks like an issue. https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/7828